# How do I display a buy label if price is less than or equal to 40% away from the 200 Week MA

Tags: pine-script

Think I'm almost done with this script. It's my first one btw so please go easy on me.
I know this is probably a really dumb question. Someone helped me earlier, but I have one thing left to program.

What someone helped me finish.
Buy labels are only displayed in bull markets, i.e. price over 200D MA.
Sell labels are only displayed in bear markets, i.e. price below 200D MA.

However, I want to reenact buy labels being displayed again IF the price is less than or equal to 40% away from the 200W MA. Makes since to buy at these levels, even in a bear market because it has historically marked near the bear market low for Bitcoin. Thanks for your help in advance! :)

```
indicator("Redlight-Greenlight", overlay=true)

GreenLightMA = ta.sma(close, 7)
RedLightEMA = ta.ema(close, 47)
BullMarket = ta.sma(close, 200)
TwoHundredWeek = ta.sma(close, 1394) <---- 200W MA i know it;s not 1,400

plot(GreenLightMA, color = color.green)
plot(RedLightEMA, color = color.red)
plot(BullMarket, color = color.orange)
plot(BearLow, color = color.gray)

buy = ta.crossover(GreenLightMA, RedLightEMA) and close > BullMarket 
sell = ta.crossover(RedLightEMA, GreenLightMA) and close < BullMarket

if (buy)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Buy")
    label.set_color(lbl, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_up)    

if (sell)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Sell")
    label.set_color(lbl, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)
```

Comment: Oh, also I need to create an exit label for the first day that closes below the 47D EMA AFTER a buy order has been enacted. And an exit label for the first day that closes above the 47D EMA after a sell signal has been enacted. Pretty sure that's everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this condition to your `buy` condition with an `or`.

```
buy = ta.crossover(GreenLightMA, RedLightEMA) and ((close > BullMarket) or (close >= TwoHundredWeek)
```

So, the first crossover must take place no matter what. Then it should either be in a bull market or above 200D MA.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I just added this to it, to meet my requirements: or (close <= BearLow * 1.40))